# Extract training data predictions from rpart

Tags: r, classification, cart, rpart

I'm wondering if there is any method to extract the class assignment of each sample in an rpart model from the training data?

E.g. in R using random forest to get the predicted class of each sample (from the training data), you can use:

```
data(iris)
rf.iris <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data = iris)
head(rf.iris$predicted)
     1      2      3      4      5      6 
setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa 
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

As far as I can tell there is no way to do this for an rpart model. I could re-predict my training data using the rpart model but for obvious reasons I don't want to do this.

Is it possible to extract the individual sample classifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to obtain the predicted classes is the `predict` function.

```
library(rpart)
rp.iris <- rpart(Species ~ ., data = iris)

pred1 <- predict(rp.iris, type = "class")

head(pred1)
#      1      2      3      4      5      6 
# setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa 
# Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

However, if you want to avoid using this function, you can use the following command to create the predictions.

```
pred2 <- setNames(factor(rp.iris$frame$yval[rp.iris$where], 
                         labels = attr(rp.iris, "ylevels")),
                  names(rp.iris$where))

identical(pred1, pred2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Hi Sven, thanks for your answer. I was under the impression that using the `predict` function would re-predict the training data, and therefore give an optimistic idea of classification accuracy? Is that not the case?

Comment: @KaanKaant Basically, the `predict` function generates the predictions in similar way. All neccesary information is stored in the object returned by `rpart`.